# Moving O365 calendar events from personal to shared group calendar issue

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I have a situation, where owner of a company needed a shared calendar.
I created a group in O365 admin panel and now i need to move a lot of events to the new one from old personal calendar.

I know, that i can copy calendars easily  in Outlook app but the calendars do not appear there somewhy. Therefore i need to use OWA and i cant find a way to copy all events in one move (not going to drag-drop 1000+ events?)

Have anyone ever faced this kind of situation?

Comment: "Cut (or copy) and paste is not working at this time. The appointments need to be added to the calendar as new items, otherwise they will not sync up to the server. "  See this link for macro method: https://www.slipstick.com/office-365/import-appointments-group-calendar/

Comment: Answering this after all is working correctly. You need to create shared mailbox instead of shared group. Then you can move all appointments from one calendar to another and all appointments and auto-events are syncing correctly. Just add a user to the group and after they sync their mailbox, the shared mailbox will appear.

Answer (score 1):

Answering this after all is working correctly. You need to create shared mailbox instead of shared group. Then you can move all appointments from one calendar to another and all appointments and auto-events are syncing correctly. Just add a user to the group and after they sync their mailbox, the shared mailbox will appear.